# NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/cfg/Configuration

Tags: hibernate, gwt, tomcat, jetty

I am using Hibernate to implement a remote procedure call in my Google Web Toolkit project.  When I run it from Eclipse as a Google "Web Application", I get a NoClassDefFoundError exception when the service is called (when I press a button on the web page):

```
Starting Jetty on port 8888
   [WARN] Exception while dispatching incoming RPC call
com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.UnexpectedException: Service method 'public abstract java.lang.String edu.mit.ll.irbenchmark.client.MetricDataTableService.getDataString(edu.mit.ll.irbenchmark.EvaluationMetric)' threw an unexpected exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/cfg/Configuration
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.encodeResponseForFailure(RPC.java:385)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:588)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall(RemoteServiceServlet.java:208)
```

But when I "GWT Compile" the project and copy the contents of directory "war" to tomcat6, it works perfectly!

The following jars are in my war/WEB-INF/lib directory:

```
antlr-3.4-complete.jar
commons-collections3-3.2.1.jar
dom4j.jar
gwt-servlet.jar
hibernate-commons-annotations-3.2.0.Final.jar
hibernate-core-3.6.9.Final.jar
hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar
IRBenchmarker.jar
javassist-3.12.0.GA.jar
jta-1.1.jar
log4j-1.2-1.2.16.jar
mysql-connector-java-5.1.16.jar
slf4j-api-1.6.4.jar
slf4j-log4j12-1.6.4.jar
```

Comment: Did this question pass the google test? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9851528/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-hibernate-cfg-configuration

Comment: Yes.  As I explicitly listed above, the hibernate jars are in the war/WEB-INF/lib library.

Answer (score 1):

Putting the library into WEB-INF/lib is not enough for Eclipse. You need to add it to the Project's classpath, too (right-click the jar, and select Build Path > Add to Build Path).

Comment: I'll add on instead on a new answer, that typically NCDFE are instances of the same class being available from two different places where as the CNFE is no class definition being found anywhere...so look for multiple hibernate jars being available

Comment: @jesse: [CNFE](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassNotFoundException.html) are thrown, "when an application tries to load in a class through its string name". [NCDFE](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError.html) are thrown if it loads a class "as part of a normal method call or as part of creating a new instance using the `new` expression".

Comment: The hibernate libraries are in the project's classpath.  I can see the class org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration under Referenced Libraries in the Package Explorer even.  Is there an easy way to tell whether there are multiple definitions of the class in my classpath?

Comment: @ChrisLercher How about in IntelliJ IDEA?

Answer (score 1):

Right click on your project and go to Properties. then goto Google-> Web Application. make sure "This project has a WAR directory" is checked and your war folder is addressed under the check box. now that you're there, it wouldn't hurt to take a look at Google-> Web Tooklit and make sure "Use Google Web Toolkit" is checked and the correct library is adressed.