# Why am I getting a NoClassDefFoundError trying to use Hibernate?

Tags: hibernate

I use Eclipse Juno. I created a dynamic web application using Hibernate. I added the Hibernate library to my project. I got the following error in my servlet:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/cfg/Configuration

Comment: please list lib and your code

Comment: [Duplicate problem][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9851528/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-hibernate-cfg-configuration

Answer (score -1):

Have you added the all the related Hibernate jar files.

Maybe Hibernate jars are not available to Tomcat.

Right click your project -> Build Path -> Configure Build Path, and remove the hibernate set from the build path. Now import the jars into the WEB-INF/lib folder