# Hibernate Configuration, Exception encountered during context initialization, Errors with HomeController and sessionFactory

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, tomcat

First of all, I am recently trying to improve myself in JAVA EE. And there is another topic, actually the same problem as mine. But the solution did not work for me. Here is the link of that topic:

[Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42772432/exception-encountered-during-context-initialization-cancelling-refresh-attempt)

Also another topic is:
[java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/cfg/Configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9851528/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-hibernate-cfg-configuration)

Anyways I will provide the errors I am facing with,

Error Message:

> Org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error >creating bean with name 'homeController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed >through field 'productDao;
>
> nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Failed to introspect bean class

Here is **HomeController**:

```
package com.emusicstore.controller;

import com.emusicstore.dao.ProductDao;
import com.emusicstore.model.Product;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @Autowired
    private ProductDao productDao;

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String home(){
        return "home";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/productList")
    public String getProducts(Model model) {
        List<Product> products = productDao.getAllProducts();
        model.addAttribute("products", products);

        return "productList";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/productList/viewProduct/{productId}")
    public String viewProduct(@PathVariable String productId, Model model) throws IOException {
        Product product = productDao.getProductById(productId);
        model.addAttribute(product);
        return "viewProduct";
    }
}
```

**Pom.xml** :

```
<groupId>com.mywebsite</groupId>
<artifactId>emusicstore</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.195</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
        <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

**ApplicationContext.xml**:

```
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">  

    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.h2.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/~/test" />
    <property name="username" value="sa" />
    <property name="password" value="" />
 </bean>


<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean" >
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties" >

        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect"> org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql" >true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>

    <property name="packagesToScan">
        <list>
            <value>com.emusicstore</value>
        </list>
    </property>

</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager" >
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

The things that I have tried:

- register bean object in applicationContext.xml

> bean id="productDao" class="com.emusicstore.dao.impl.ProductDaoImpl" />

- Annotating ProductDao class with @Component
- Adding Hibernate Core jar file to Project Structure

**Here is also the pic of my Project Structure:** [Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H30Ov.png)

Full error stack:

```
WARNING [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] 
org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.refresh 
Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh 
attempt: 
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error 
creating bean with name 'homeController': Unsatisfied dependency 
expressed through field 'productDao'; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating 
bean with name 'sessionFactory': Failed to introspect bean class 
[org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean] for lookup 
method metadata: could not find class that it depends on; nested 
exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate
/cfg/Configuration

SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1]  
org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext 
Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: 
Error creating bean with name 'homeController': Unsatisfied dependency 
expressed through field 'productDao'; 
nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating 
bean with name 'sessionFactory': 
Failed to introspect bean class 
[org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean] for lookup    
method metadata: 
could not find class that it depends on; nested exception is   
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/cfg/Configuration
```

Comment: Can you add `<context:component-scan base-package="com.emusicstore" />` to your` applicationContext.xml` and try?

Comment: Nope, it did not work.

Comment: okay. Have you got the same error?

Comment: Yes, exactly same one.

Comment: Can you paste the complete error stack trace?

Comment: I have added to the topic

Comment: If you are using tomcat, refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9851528/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-hibernate-cfg-configuration. Root cause could be because of this `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/cfg/Configuration`

Answer (score 0):

try to add

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-tools</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

to you `pom.xml` file