# Could not find class to hibernate configuration?

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, tomcat, intellij-idea

I am using Intellij, Maven, Tomcat, Hibernate and JEE to create some app.
When I try to run my application through Intellij through Tomcat there is an error in the webrowser:

```
Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:579)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:461)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
Root Cause

javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/cfg/Configuration
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:909)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:838)
    org.apache.jsp.addAdvertisement_jsp._jspService(addAdvertisement_jsp.java:176)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:438)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
Root Cause

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/cfg/Configuration
    com.advertisement.entity.AdvertisementDAO.init(AdvertisementDAO.java:29)
    org.apache.jsp.addAdvertisement_jsp._jspService(addAdvertisement_jsp.java:148)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:438)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
Root Cause

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1352)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1180)
    com.advertisement.entity.AdvertisementDAO.init(AdvertisementDAO.java:29)
    org.apache.jsp.addAdvertisement_jsp._jspService(addAdvertisement_jsp.java:148)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:438)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
```

My project structure looks like this:

[image]

When I run JUnit test all works correctly.

```
import com.advertisement.entity.Advertisement;
import com.advertisement.entity.AppUser;
import junit.framework.TestCase;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

/**
 * Unit test for simple App.
 */
public class AppTest extends TestCase {

    public void testAppUser() {
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure()
                .buildSessionFactory();
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();

        AppUser user = new AppUser("firstuser");
        session.save(user);

        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
    }

    public void testAppAdvertisement() {
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure()
                .buildSessionFactory();
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();

        Advertisement advertisement = new Advertisement();
        session.save(advertisement);

        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
    }
}
```

The problem is when I deploy it to Tomcat and after that run. It's seems to me that Tomcat does not see the Hibernate or Hibernate's configuration, some Hibernate config path is incorrect?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9853106/3959856

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/cfg/Configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9851528/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-hibernate-cfg-configuration)

Comment: This is not duplicated because of even fact that this article is about eclipse and this is about intellij.