# Why i can't run hibernate maven app from console?

Tags: java, hibernate, maven

I am trying to run a Hibernate application. I can do it from NetBeans IDE, when I am going to command line, with mvn install it builds successfully but when I am trying to run the jar file in target folder (java -jar hibernate-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar) I am getting the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/cfg/Configuration
        at hibernate.HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:11)
        at hibernate.SmartDevice.main(SmartDevice.java:13)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 2 more
```

It doesn't find the Configuration class of Hibernate, but I added the hibernate-core dependency in my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.1.Final</version>

        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.h2database/h2 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.197</version>
        </dependency>  

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.persistence/persistence-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.2.1</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
      <!-- Build an executable JAR -->
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                      <archive>
                        <manifest>
                          <mainClass>hibernate.SmartDevice</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                      </archive>
                    </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


    <name>hibernate</name>

</project>
```

Here is my hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">org.h2.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1</property>
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
        <mapping class="hibernate.User"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Should I add something else? Or why is this error? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/cfg/Configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9851528/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-hibernate-cfg-configuration)

Comment: Can you post your pom.xml?

Comment: How exactly do you run your `.jar` file? Do you add hibernate core to the class path while running?

Comment: I inserted the full pom.xml above. 

i run the .jar only with this command from the console:
    java -jar hibernate-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar

How can i add then hibernate to class path while running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ClassNotFoundException` means that the `org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration` class in not included in your classpath. Looking for that class in the IDE, we see it is included in the `hibernate-core-5.4.1-Final.jar` file.

By running `java -jar hibernate-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`, the additional dependencies are missing.

There are some ways to package your jar with the required dependencies, one is by using the `maven-assembly-plugin`, or by using the shade plugin.

As a "manual" alternative, you can cd to your project root folder (containing the `pom.xml` file), and execute

```
mvn clean package
mvn dependency:copy-dependencies
java -cp target/*;target/dependency/* hibernate.SmartDevice
```

The `dependency` plugin copies all needed jars to the `target\dependency` folder, and the last command adds all jars to the classpath and runs your java class.

**edit** the above commands are for Windows; on Linux you would use ":" in place of ";"

Comment: Thank you! I tried the "manual" way and it worked. Now i am getting the same output as in netbeans!